# I tried to delete my account but it didn't work

Tags: support, deleted-users

There was a nice count down at the top of my profile indicating how long until my account would be deleted. The countdown should have ended about 3 hours ago, but obviously I'm still here. Is there something more I need to do for this to work?

Comment: Yes. Be patient, and stop expecting instant gratification. Some things just take a little longer. Relax, put your feet up, watch a little TV or take a nap. :-)

Comment: But, but, but... the shiny count down said I'd have instant gratification. :) Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something important.

Comment: I'm amazed this was noticed. If I ever delete an account, I press the button and then walk away permanently. I only ever notice if I receive an email or something from the service again

Comment: @Joe It's important to me given the circumstances that I confirm the deletion happens.

Comment: @Avilyn of course, every situation is different and should be handled differently. My comment wasn't a "dig" at you, more of a, well... comment.

Comment: May be related from MSE: [Accounts still there hours after deletion countdown completed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248200/accounts-still-there-hours-after-deletion-countdown-completed)

Comment: @Joe I didn't take it as a dig. Just thought an explanation of why someone (me) might care might be interesting. :)

Comment: See the "Why wasn't my account deleted immediately after the timer expiring?" section of [answer to: "How can I delete my account?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7979/271271).

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes, accounts are just *too awesome* for the automatic deletion process to complete, and the system summons a human being to do a final check. We don't mean to delay the process, we just don't want to make mistakes, and we'd like the opportunity to at least *see* why someone with quite a bit of participation left, even if only to dispense diamond justice if it was due to someone else being a jerk.

'Twasn't the case though, sorry about the delay, we usually process these in a manner that it's not noticed, but once in a while we <strike>get really busy</strike> forget to check the damn queue.

Comment: the very act of _completely_ answering a question makes it impossible for asker to accept. That's so... meta